# cut command, order not preserved?

Tags: cut

I have a sample file:-

```
[root@localhost base_filters]# cat shortlist
2233|charles harris  |g.m.     |sales     |12/12/52| 90000
9876|bill johnson    |director |production|03/12/50|130000
5678|robert dylan    |d.g.m.   |marketing |04/19/43| 85000
2365|john woodcock   |director |personnel |05/11/47|120000
5423|barry wood      |chairman |admin     |08/30/56|160000
```

I wanted to flip the names in the file such that there is a comma `,` after the last name i.e for example a name should appear as harris,charles.

I tried the following command:-

```
[root@localhost base_filters]# tr -s ' ' < shortlist | cut -d\| -f2 | cut -d' ' -f2,1
charles harris
bill johnson
robert dylan
john woodcock
barry wood
```

I want last name to appear first so I specified field 2 and then 1 but this doesn't seem to work. Any Ideas about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 all, for their support :). I found an even simpler solution:-

```
[root@localhost base_filters]# paste -d, <(cut -d\| -f2 shortlist| cut -d' ' -f2) <(cut -d\| -f2 shortlist| cut -d' ' -f1)
harris,charles
johnson,bill
dylan,robert
woodcock,john
wood,barry
```

Answer (score 4):

This is done easily using `awk`. First print out the name, then pipe the output to awk again (this time using space as the file separator).

```
awk -F "|" '{print $2}' extract.txt | awk -F " " '{print $2 "," $1}'
```

Answer (score 4):

The man page of cut says

> Selected input is written in the same order that it is read, and is
>   written exactly  once.

So you have to use another tool instead of cut. For example sed, awk, perl, python or bash.

Answer (score 4):

The following function will use only Bash built-ins ( in case that you want to use Bash ) to do what you want:

```
foo () 
{ 
    local filename="$1"

    while IFS='|' read -r pre name suf; do
        l="$pre|${name#* },${name% *}|$suf";
        printf '%s\n' "$l";
    done < "$filename"
}
```

The [IFS variable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS) is set to | and 'read' reads every line at a time from **"$1"** ( your file ) and divides it into three parts, **$pre $name** and **$suf**, according to the IFS value.

$**pre** value is set to be the field before the name, **$name** is set to be the name itself which you want to swap ( the second field ) and **$suf** is the rest of the line.

I use [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) ( also search for Parameter Expansion in `man bash` ) to split the **$name** field.

`"${name#* }"` will cut the first name, leaving us with the last name.

`"${name% *}"` will cut the last name, leaving us with the first name.

**Usage:** foo [/path/to/file.txt]

**Sample output:**

```
nylon100@~$ cat>file.txt
123|first1 last1|foo|bar|date|baz
456|first2 last2|foo|bar|date|baz
789|first3 last3|foo|bar|date|baz

nylon100@~$ foo file.txt
123|last1,first1|foo|bar|date|baz
456|last2,first2|foo|bar|date|baz
789|last3,first3|foo|bar|date|baz
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, cut doesn't change the order, it just selects data from each line.

You'd need to use `sed` or `awk` like:

```
sed 's/^\([^|]*|\)\([^|]\{1,\}\) \([^ |]\{1,\}\)/\1\3,\2/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tr -s ' ' < shortlist | cut -d\| -f2 | tr '\n' ' ' | tac -s' ' | \
  sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]//' -e 's/  /\n/g' | sort
```

Or, if you have many such files:

```
sortnames () {
  tr -s ' ' < $1 | cut -d\| -f2 | tr '\n' ' ' | tac -s' ' | \
    sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]//' -e 's/  /\n/g' | sort
}
```